# How to Create data with read_only_fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

and facing a issue with read_only fields suppose I have the follwoing serailizer

```
`class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created']
        read_only_fields = ['account_name']`
```

where the account_name (in the Account model this field can not be null) is set to read_only because I do not want to update its data after creation but while creating the data using I am passing the account_name in the serializer but its excluding the account_name and giving the error "account_name" can not be null

can anyone give me the solution for this how I can create a data with read_only field which can not be null

I have tried to remove it from read_only_field but by doing this the account_name can be update but I don't want to update it after creation

Comment: Please add Account Model in Question for a batter answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to make the field `account_name` writable for the create API endpoint, but read only for update API.

Using `read_only_fields` won't work here, because DRF will always ignore any data sent for these fields in the request. So, it needs to be handled conditionally.

One (quick) way is to handle this in `validate(self, attrs)` or `validate_account_name(self, value)` method. For example:

```
def validate_account_name(self, value):
    if self.instance.pk:
        return self.instance.account_name
    else:
        return value
```

This will essentially assign the existing value to the field if it's a update call.

This will, however, won't reflect in the docs automatically if you're using something like swagger/openapi based documentation. To fix that, you either specify the request fields in docs or create two serializer class (update inherited from create method class), and assign read only fields in the update class. You'll then need to specify the appropriate serializer class for their respective methods.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take is to create two separate serialziers, one for response and one for request and use it properly to the HTTP method you choose

```
class ResponseAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created']
        read_only_fields = ['account_name']

class RequestAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created']
```

With this you can validate and set the fields that you need in each case.